# Can I transfer PS2 data from my PS3 onto a PS2 memory card?

Tags: ps3, ps2

My old PS3 died recently and I had some PS2 memory on it. I'm considering buying a slim PS3 since it has more memory, but since it isn't compatible with PS2 games, the data will have no purpose on it.

Now say I manage to have all of my data transferred to a slim PS3, including the PS2 data. If I bought a memory card adapter and put a PS2 memory card into it, would it be at all possible for me to transfer my PS2 data on my PS3 onto a PS2 memory card?

Comment: I feel for you.  I lost a PS3, too, with all my saves on it.  Haven't yet figured out a way to get the stuff off of it.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, as long as you use the [official memory card adaptor](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000K1GZIU): while they might work fine for reading, third-party adapters are hit-or-miss when it comes to writing back to PS2 memory cards.

[PS3 Explained has a writeup](http://ps3explained.com/intermediate/ps2-memory-card-transfer/), but the general workflow is:

1. Connect the memory card adapter to the PS3 via one of the USB ports in the front and insert the physical PS3 memory card.
2. Under the Game section of the XMB, select the *Memory Card Utitlity (PS/PS2)* option, navigate to your virtual memory cards, press <kbd>△</kbd>, select the "copy" function, and choose the physical memory card.